# When is the right time and place to call a jquery function in form validation?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jquery function that is called on form submit. It makes an ajax request to the server and gets a JSON response with the error messages that it should display at the login page where the form is. The problem is that I get the error messages in case of error, but if the information is correct the I keep staying at the login page.

The error messages are defined with the `form-validation` library of codeigniter.

```
function login()
{
    $(".text-danger").remove();
    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
    $("#loginForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response) {
                if(response.success===false) {
                    $('.text-danger').remove();
                    if(response.message instanceof Object) {
                        $.each(response.message, function(index, value) {
                            var id = $("#"+index);
                            id
                                .closest('.form-group')
                                .removeClass('has-error')
                                .removeClass('has-success')
                                .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                                .after(value);
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".message").html('<div class="text-danger" role="alert">'+
                                           '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.message+
                                           '</div>');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

}
```

Comment: If you are supposed to go somewhere else, don't use Ajax - just go where you need to be

Comment: This is a login form I'm talking about. After clicking the login button, the user has to go somewhere if the credentials are correct

Comment: your question is not clear. the time to verify user input, is obviously, before you invoke your ajax call. if you wish to make your users even happier, verify each control, after the user left it and its no longer in focus (onBlur)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying anything on success, you can do this by adding else and then directing providing a function, see here:

```
$.ajax({
  url: form.attr('action'),
  type: form.attr('method'),
  data: form.serialize(),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
    if (resp.success === false) {
      $('.text-danger').remove();
      if (resp.message instanceof Object) {
        $.each(resp.message, function(index, value) {
          var id = $("#" + index);
          id.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success').addClass(value.length > 0
            ? 'has-error'
            : 'has-success').after(value);
        });
      } else {
        $(".message").html('<div class="text-danger" role="alert">' +
          '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> </strong>' + resp.message + '</div>');
      }
      //Here you can redirect to the login page
    } else {
      //Just replace the below with your page location
      console.log(resp);
      window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    }
  },
  error: function(req, status, err) {
    console.log('something went wrong', status, err);
  }
});
```

Tested and working:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
    if (resp.success === false) {
      $('.text-danger').remove();
      if (resp.message instanceof Object) {
        $.each(resp.message, function(index, value) {
          var id = $("#" + index);
          id.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success').addClass(value.length > 0
            ? 'has-error'
            : 'has-success').after(value);
        });
      } else {
        $(".message").html('<div class="text-danger" role="alert">' +
          '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> </strong>' + resp.message + '</div>');
      }
      //Here you can redirect to the login page
    } else {
      //Just replace the below with your page location
      console.log(resp);
      window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    }
  },
  error: function(req, status, err) {
    console.log('something went wrong', status, err);
  }
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't take me anywhere

Comment: Hi, can you try the code now and tell me what is being logged in the console? Also do you get redirected now?

Comment: I tried it and there's nothing in console and I don't get redirected.

Comment: Can you give it a go again?

Comment: I get a `data is not defined` error at the `console.log(data)` inside the `success:function(response)`

Comment: Hi Eri, that may have been a typo, its super late! Check the latest edit... I tested it and it works :) Well with the testing URL. The problem may be wth the form itself.

Comment: @eri Your response is probably not being returned as json and you need to parse it first.

Comment: Solved it, I had an issue in my controller